# PNG read and write with Java increases file size

Tags: java, image-processing

Got a problem when reading and writing a png file. I read it with ImageIO to a byte array and then write this byte array again using ImageIO. But the file size increases significantly. How can this happen?

```
public BufferedImage toBufferedImage(InputStream inputstream) {
    try {
        return ImageIO.read(inputstream);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Can't convert to buffered image", e);
    }
}

public byte[] toByteArray(BufferedImage bufferedImage, String filetype) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, filetype, output);
        return output.toByteArray();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
}
```

**Follow up**: is there any library to support compressed PNGs that is written in Java and does not need any native code?

Comment: I wonder if it is adding an additional header of some sort on write or adding extra data to the header.  A good way to check if this is so is to open both files in something like Beyond Compare and see if all the differences are at the beginning (where the header is).  If not then the differences may be everywhere, which may suggest that it is adding blank data all over the file.  I doubt it is because it has re-encoded the file - but that could be a possibility.

Comment: I would imagine that the writer isn't being very clever about compression. Perhaps there are better output stream or writer implementations that can compress the format? The javadoc in the package alludes to interfaces with this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.io.File%29) says it's decoding the input file, so it's not being held in memory as a PNG:

> Returns a BufferedImage as the result of decoding a supplied File with an ImageReader chosen automatically from among those currently registered. The File is wrapped in an ImageInputStream. If no registered ImageReader claims to be able to read the resulting stream, null is returned.

When it writes it back, it has to re-encode the PNG file, and Java's PNG encoding doesn't seem to be as efficient as whatever created your original file.

Comment: we finally used pngj (http://code.google.com/p/pngj/) for writing which seems to work quite well for what we need.

Answer (score 5):

This is most likely due to the compression algorithm being different between Java and whatever created the original PNG.

Answer (score 1):

The PNG writer supplied with the JDK does not support compression. You can quickly check this with:

```
w = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("png").next();
p = w.getDefaultWriteParam();
print("Can compress? "+p.canWriteCompressed());
// Can compress? false
```

It's possible that imageio-ext or jai-imageio include a png writer with compression support: http://java.net/projects/imageio/